# Flex: ItemEditor losing focus!

Tags: apache-flex, itemeditor

Here's an image of what my problem is:
I am using a combo-box as a Datagrid ItemEditor (Not just Renderer, my Renderer is a Label, double clicking on a cell makes the combo-box visible, as is the case with all item editors)

Now, selecting one of the entries in the combo-box is no problem. But my problem is only when i select the "Fruit" , which in turn pops open another layer called "Select Fruit" dialog

Questions:

How do i keep item editor, while the focus is on the layer; right now as soon as i click on the fruit , my handler popsup the "Select Fruit" dialog and the focus is on the layer. Once the focus goes out of the editor, the ItemEditor goes away and ItemRenderer label comes back.

I want to keep the ItemEditor alive! where do I hook up interms of events like begin/end ItemEdit etc?

[image: Flex: Item editor, losing focus!]

Comment: Can we see some code?  I would probably just create an item renderer with a custom editor rather than using the built in item editor, then you have full control over what is shown and when (with some no doubt clever states you'll put in there)  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your itemEditor alive by listening for DataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_END. Then you have a lot more control to do what you want. Some FYI from my blog:

DataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_END
- Dispatched when focus is removed from the cell
- List-based control’s default event listener will

1) use the .editorDataFrield property to deterine the property of the item editor to store the edited data; In a default TextInput control’s item editor, the “text” property would contain the new data.

2) Invoke destoryItemEditor() depending on the reason of the event

- You can interrupt the default List-based control’s default event listener by using event.preventDefault() to

a) Modify the data returned from the item editor

b) Examine/Validate the data entered into the item editor; If the data is incorrect, you can halt Flex passing the data back from the item editor into the list-based control

http://knowledge.lapasa.net/?p=153

Answer (score 0):

Try losing focus of your ItemEditor. Goto Combo Box Change Listener

```
protected function comboBox_changeHandler(event:ListEvent):void
{
// set focus out event on datagrid. Its like clicking outside the datagrid
event.target.parent.parent.parent.dispatchEvent(new FocusEvent(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT);

}
```